# Do the various HLS files have to be stored in separate folders?

Tags: amazon-s3, http-live-streaming, video.js

**Background:**
The [HLS RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216.html) doesn't seem to mention anything about this. I'm creating a script that generates a `720p.m3u8` file for a series of 720p resolution `.ts` files. Then it uses FFMPEG to generate 480p `.ts` files using the 720p `.ts` files and generates a `480p.m3u8` file.
Then it generates a master `playlist.m3u8` file which points to the `720p.m3u8` and `480p.m3u8` files.

**Master:**

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3145728,RESOLUTION=1280x720"
720p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1572864,RESOLUTION=854x480"
480p.m3u8
```

**Question:**

1. Is it ok to have all the `.ts` files of all resolutions stored in the same folder along with their respective `m3u8` files and the master `m3u8` file? Or should the `.ts` and `.m3u8` files of each resolution be stored in separate folders and the master `m3u8` be in the parent folder? Like this:

   #EXTM3U
   #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3145728,RESOLUTION=1280x720"
   720p_folder/720p.m3u8
   #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1572864,RESOLUTION=854x480"
   480p_folder/480p.m3u8
2. The [multivariant playlist here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/example_playlists_for_http_live_streaming/creating_a_multivariant_playlist) shows `m3u8` locations as full URL's `http://example.com/low/index.m3u8`. Is that how it should be, or can it be a relative folder path like I've shown above (`480p_folder/480p.m3u8`)?

This is for accessing via `VideoJS` from various client browsers across the world, and the `.ts` and `.m3u8` files will be stored on an AWS S3 server.

Comment: The [HLS spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-hls-rfc8216bis) allows for each URI to be relative or absolute .. absolute is common as often a manifest will be served in a different location, necessitating a full URI for the content, but that depends on factors outside of the spec.  The spec also makes no mention about folders or shared prefixes, that's purely an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Folders for the different renditions are commonly used but there is absolutely no requirement for it.
2. All URLs in a Multivariant playlist (used to be called master playlist) and in the different variant playlists can be relative or absolute, without really any restrictions. Things to consider here are:

   1. With absolute URLs, it's easy to host just the playlist files elsewhere while all URLs will still work
   2. With relative URLs, it's easy to move or copy the content to other locations as long as m3u8 playlist and media files are kept together.

As a side note, you should consider using `mp4` chunks instead of `ts` unless you have a technical reason not to. There are hardly any devices left that only support `ts` but not `mp4`, and for using some HLS features, the use of `mp4` is required (at least for Apple devices), e.g.:

- Using the more efficient HEVC codec [1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/http_live_streaming_hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices#2969487)
- Using xHE-AAC, Apple Lossless, or FLAC audio [2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/http_live_streaming_hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices#2969503)
- Using the IMSC1 subtitle format [3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/http_live_streaming_hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices#2969509)